# Mathematical expression for mean of sum of pairs

Tags: equations, mathematics

Hello everyone I have a matrix such as :

[image]

and I do the mean of sum of all pair such as

```
(H1H2)+(H1H3)+(H1H4)+(H1H5)+(H2H3)+(H2H4)+(H2H5)+(H3H4)+(H3H5)+(H4H5)/nb pairs
```

and I wondered how can I exprime that expression into a mathematical expression and then into a latex code please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Is it ok, for notational purposes, to refer to the `i,j` element of matrix `H1`, i=1,...5, j=1,...,5`, as `H_{ij}`?

Comment: Hello, yes I guess we can say that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of at least two representations of the "mean of sum of pairs" in LaTeX code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for "\smashoperator" macro
\begin{document}
\raggedright % optional
The ``mean of sum of pairs'' of $H_{n\times n}$ may be expressed as either
\[
\frac{2}{n(n-1)} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j>i} H_{i,j}
\quad\text{or as}\quad
(n(n-1)/2)^{-1}\smashoperator{\sum_{\substack{i=1,\dots,n\\j>i}}} H_{i,j}\,.
\]
\end{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks nice thank you very much Mico